# how to connect our android app with url and passing data to this url

Tags: javascript, android, android-networking

I need to write an Android application that will request a url through this app, I need to pass some data to store them in that url.

The url page use Gethttp to get data from the http request.

So any idea to join these pieces to connect these together?

Answer (score 0):

You can using QueryString like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/service.php?Param1=5&Param2=teste
```

If you use string, you should encode first.

```
"http://www.mywebsite.com/service.php?Param1=5&Param2=" + URLEncoder.encode("teste");
```

Comment: what is the complete code that i get it to passing my data to some url

Comment: There isn't more code... You now can build your own parameters. The service receive those parameters and do something. Only code is: URLEncoder, than you can find in: java.net.URLEncoder

Comment: the value of my parameters is  URLEncoder.encode("teste") !!!!
and i where have i this url ???

Comment: This is a simple url enconding. If you try enconding URLEncoder.encode("my test 123"), the result is: "my%20test%20123", because the url does not support special characters.

Comment: ok >>>>
but what about the url >>> where can i add it to the code ???
is it to have new intent with this url ??